# Auto completion in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm willing to experiment with WebGL and currently using **three.js** to make my content.
My editor of choice was **SublimeText 2**.

The problem I have is that *I do not get auto completion unless I use that variable/method/package before*. So just pressing a dot char and expecting to get a full list of variables and methods doesn't work.

Is there a way to do that in either SublimeText 2 or SublimeText 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) plugin, available through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net). Set up properly, it will index files and directories you tell it to, and will provide "semi-intelligent" autocompletion for classes, methods, function arguments, etc. I haven't used it much with JavaScript, but if its performance in Python coding is any indicator, it's a huge help to more rapid coding, as well as working with sometimes-unfamiliar libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the atucomplete for `Three.js` by installing the `Three.js Autocomplete` package using package control:

> Threejs sublime can be installed through package control.
>
> ```
> Command+Shift+P
> Package Control: Install Package
> Select Three.js Autocomplete
> ```

Or you can install it manually by getting it form the repository:
https://github.com/blackjk3/threejs-sublime

> If everything is installed correctly you should be able to start typing 'THREE.' and get auto completion. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Either the [CodeIntel](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) or [Tern](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/tern_for_sublime) plugin should work.